# rasterio.plot gives different shape using extent after transformation

Tags: python, rasterio, affine-transformation

I plot the following tiff

[image]

I plot it using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rasterio import plot

def plot(self) -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 7))
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
    ax.axis('equal')
    plot.show(self.dst.read(),
              cmap='Greens_r',
              title='rows/columns')
```

Next, I rotate the tiff

[image]

This is done using:

```
import cv2
import rasterio 
from affine import Affine

def rotate(self, angle: float):
    center = [int(self.dst.width / 2.0),
              int(self.dst.height / 2.0)]
    
    kwargs = self.dst.meta.copy()
    # copied from imutils.rotate_bound() 
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, np.radians(-angle), 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])
    kwargs.update({
        'transform': self.dst.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, center),
        'width': int((self.dst.height * sin) + (self.dst.width * cos)),
        'height': int((self.dst.height * cos) + (self.dst.width * sin))
    })

    with rasterio.open(f'{PATH}/rotated green.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, self.dst.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(self.dst, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=self.dst.transform,
                src_crs=self.crs,
                dst_transform=self.dst.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, center),
                dst_crs=self.crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest
            )

    self.dst = rasterio.open(f'{PATH}/rotated green.tif')
```

Now I want to show the actual coordinates of the crs. I change my plot-function slightly

```
def plot(self) -> None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 7))
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
    ax.axis('equal')
    plot.show(self.dst.read(),
              extent=[self.dst.bounds.left, self.dst.bounds.right, self.dst.bounds.bottom, self.dst.bounds.top],
              cmap='Greens_r',
              title='xy-coordinates')
```

This looks as expected.

[image]

However, when I plot the rotated tiff now I get:

[image]

Why is my rotated contour smaller/narrower if we use extent? The non-rotated contour is exactly the same for rows/cols and xy-coordinates

Comment: Because you've changed the extent of the plot?

Comment: yes, I assumed that was the case. But I also add a new width and height in `kwargs`? I assumed that the rotation and the new bounds would result in the same plot?